# Kafka retention policy not working as expected

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to delete some records after some time. For testing purpose I've used the command

`bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name my-topic-name --add-config retention.ms=1`

Which in my understanding should purge some records (or at least make them disappear when a consumer start reading messages from the beginning) after 1 milisecond.

But what actually happened is weird. Every about 5 minutes, the last 5 minutes messages are deleted and do not appear anymore. so for instance if I send a message every minute, I would have 5 messages, then 0, the 5 again, then 0, etc.

So I guess my command isn't working at all ?

I use kafka 2.8.0

Many thanks !
Kev

Comment: Btw Zookeeper flag is deprecated. Use bootstrap-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 'retention.ms' property will work when log.cleanup.policy = 'delete'

   - This should be set at your end, i.e why data is getting cleaned up
2. 'log.retention.check.interval.ms' should be less then **retention.ms** if you want your data to be deleted after every 'retention.ms' milliseconds.

[image]
Screenshot from [official-doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/)

Since the default value of 'log.retention.check.interval.ms' is 5 min, hence messages are deleted after every 5 minutes.

Comment: Hey many thanks for your answer ! Can you explain the bullet point under "1" ? I don't understand it well ?

Comment: @Kevin delete is the default cleanup policy, so I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: What i meant is - if the log cleanup policy is not ‘delete’ in that case the events wont get purged. However since u mentioned that they are getting deleted, this doesn’t seem to be the case. 

Please do accept it as answer if it helped

Comment: "log.retention.ms": 10000, "log.cleanup.policy": "delete", "log.retention.check.interval.ms": 2000, "log.roll.ms": 10000

... yet not working ....