# I can't delete data from a specific topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to delete data for a specific topic, but I can't.

I use the following command to how much data exit in the topic:

```
/opt/kafka-server/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue --bootstrap-server db1-internal:9092 --command-config /etc/kafka_server/internal-client.properties | grep sv_
```

Its output:

```
Consumer group 'node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue' has no active members.
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 13         139607986       139667550       59564           -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 5          88089516        88089516        0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 9          27406929        27407207        278             -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 14         210728287       210895182       166895          -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 6          142975495       142975495       0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 10         47343832        47343832        0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 1          21284052        21284052        0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 15         93899701        93946783        47082           -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 7          60633369        60633369        0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 11         203115486       203217743       102257          -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 2          205871108       205871108       0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 12         75944736        75975720        30984           -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 4          78316971        78316971        0               -               -               -
node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue sv_if_monitoring_republish_results 3          8357442         8357442         0               -               -               -
```

The cleanup policy (cleanup.polica configuration) is not explicitly configured, so its default value is ***delete***.

My first try was to set *retention.ms* to 1s:

```
/opt/kafka-server/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper pp1-internal:2181 --alter --entity-type topics  --entity-name sv_if_monitoring_republish_results  --add-config retention.ms=1000  --command-config  /etc/kafka_zookeeper/zookeeper_client_jaas.conf
```

I confirmed that the parameter has been overridden:

```
/opt/kafka-server/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper pp1-internal:2181 --topics-with-overrides | grep sv_if_monitoring_republish_results
```

Produced the output

```
Topic: sv_if_monitoring_republish_results       PartitionCount: 16      ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=33554432,retention.ms=1000
```

I waited for some 10 minutes and the topic data were not deleted.

Then I found [a post on here on tackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67617626/kafka-retention-policy-not-working-as-expected) that says
log.retention.check.interval.ms < retention.ms

log.retention.check.interval.ms is set to 5 minutes (300000), so I set retention.ms to 6 minutes (360000) but it didn't work either:

```
/opt/kafka-server/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper pp1-internal:2181 --alter --entity-type topics  --entity-name sv_if_monitoring_republish_results  --add-config retention.ms=360000  --command-config  /etc/kafka_zookeeper/zookeeper_client_jaas.conf
```

Then checked to be sure that the parameter retention.ms was updated. It was. Here is the result I got:

```
Topic: sv_if_monitoring_republish_results       PartitionCount: 16      ReplicationFactor: 2    Configs: segment.bytes=33554432,retention.ms=360000
```

Again I waited for some 10 minutes and the topic data were not deleted.

**Edit 1**

I executed the command below from the same machine where is Kafka

```
kafka-delete-records.sh  --bootstrap-server  db1-internal:9092 -offset-json-file /tmp/delete-sv_if_monitoring_republish_results.json
```

but all partitions timed out with error messages similar to

```
partition: sv_if_monitoring_republish_results-1 error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

I'm pretty sure it is not a problem of connectivity / misconfiguration because I successfully run other commands. Eg

```
/opt/kafka-server/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe --group node_monitoring_if_data_if_from_queue --bootstrap-server db1-internal:9092 --command-config /etc/kafka_server/internal-client.properties | grep sv_
```

Anyone had this problem? Has any tip? Am I missing something?

Notes:

- Kafka version: 2.4.0.
- It is NOT running in Docker
- content of /internal-client.properties: security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
  sasl.mechanism=PLAIN

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Only **closed** log segments will be deleted. You have a topic config `segment.bytes` of about 33MB, and it's unclear how large your events really are. So, it's possible that data is being deleted, just not in the segments you expect.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The 5th column of the data I showed on my post has values as  59564 and 166895. These are the number of events in the partitions.

Why do you say I have around events? Where am I mistaken?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't scroll. Was looking at the partition numbers, then added all those